# Monitoring status of Oozie jobs submitted through Python subprocess

Tags: python, hadoop, oozie

I'm triggering an Oozie workflow as a shell command executed via Python's subprocess module.

```
Popen("oozie job -config workflow.properties -run".split())
```

The execution of the remainder of my program depends on success or failure of various actions in this workflow. When triggering the Oozie job interactively, I get back a Oozie jobID which I can use to monitor the success/failure status of the job using

```
oozie job -info <jobId>
```

I want to access the status of various action nodes programmatically, through Python. Is there a way to accomplish this?

**What I've tried so far:** 
An Oozie MapReduce action places a `_SUCCESS` file in the output folder upon successful job completion. I polled for the presence of this file every 2 seconds. However, I'm wondering if there is a direct API/Shell call to get status of action nodes.

**Related(ish) questions**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588495/python-subprocess-with-oozie) post talks about the reverse problem: that of triggering Python jobs through Oozie and doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have RESTAPI to access the Logs status.. and even to submit the Oozie job and monitor it!! WE can pass the RESTAPIs to the oozie-server we can able to take it out periodically!!BTW it can be applicable for all the jobs which we can submitted in the oozie.

for you ref : https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WebServicesAPI.html